# If $S$ and $T$ and bounded self-adjoint linear operators on a Hilbert space $H$, show that $\tilde{T}=\alpha S +\beta T$ is self-adjoint.

Tags: functional-analysis

If $S$ and $T$ and bounded self-adjoint linear operators on a Hilbert space $H$ and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real, show that $\tilde{T}=\alpha S +\beta T$ is self-adjoint.

Can't figure out where to start. Any and all help would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What is the adjoint of $\alpha S + \beta T$?